# How do I get Excel to run a query for each row in a spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, query

Is there a way to run an MS Query for each row in a spreadsheet?  For example, I have a sheet that looks like this:

```
CustomerID
111
222
333
```

I have the customer's address in a database, and I'd like to annotate each row in the sheet with the customer's city, like so:

```
CustomerID     City
111            Chicago
222            New York
333            Los Angeles
```

Comment: What format is the database?  What version of excel do you use?

Comment: the database is an obscure format, but I can get to it through an ODBC connection.  I'm using Excel 2007.

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler to do a single query pulling results to another sheet of all CustomerIDs, then use vlookup in a formula to find the city for that CustomerID in those results.

Comment: I thought about that, but I have about 3MM customers.  that would take a long time to download and a lot of RAM to store in Excel, no?

Comment: Might I ask, how the list of CustomerIDs are being generated in the first place? Or is dataentry occurring, and you need to lookup the appropriate city at the entry stage?

Comment: an infinite number of monkeys (aka "the finance department") comes up with the spreadsheet via a process that is opaque to me.  They just asked me to annotate the sheet.  I can make the annotations by writing a Python program, but I thought there might be a clever way to do this directly in Excel.

Comment: for the quantity of CustomerIDs, you are right, pulling it into a sheet to use a vlookup on, won't work, unless you broke the query results into different sections based upon CustomerID ranges, and then adjusted the formula to look at the appropriate one. scripting a query on each individual item would probably be fairly long processing. Python might be a good choice